# Having trouble with creating class's of Array List instance, keep getting same error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Having a hard time with a piece of code I am working on. Basically, Im trying to create an instance of the Tranctions with it being stored in arraylist. I keep getting the error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>   at Account.(Account.java:14)
>   at Transactions.(Transactions.java:10)

I am really confused about making this whole thing work, and am really stuck. And need some direction. 
Here is the code I am using.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Account {
protected int id; 
private String name;

protected double balance;     
private double annualInterestRate;
private java.util.Date dateCreated;
ArrayList<Object> transaction =  new ArrayList<Object>();

Transactions tr = new Transactions(); 

public Account(){}

public Account(int ID, double BALANCE){
this.id = ID;   
this.balance = BALANCE;
}

public Account(int ID, double BALANCE, String NAME){
    this.id = ID;   
    this.balance = BALANCE;
    this.name = NAME; 
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
}

public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
}

public java.util.Date getDate(){
    return dateCreated;
}

public double getMonthlyInterestRate(){
    double AR = this.annualInterestRate /100; 
    double monthlyInterestRate = (AR/ 12);
    return this.balance * monthlyInterestRate;

}

public void withdraw(double Amount_Withdraw){

this.balance = this.balance - Amount_Withdraw;  
String Description = "This is a Withdraw";
//Object Array = tr.Transactions1('w',Amount_Withdraw,balance,Description); 
transaction.add(tr.Transactions1('w',Amount_Withdraw,balance,Description));

}

public void deposit(double Amount_Deposit){
    this.balance = this.balance + Amount_Deposit;
    String Description = "This is a Deposit";
    //Object Array = tr.Transactions1('w',Amount_Withdraw,balance,Description); 
    transaction.add(tr.Transactions1('w',Amount_Deposit,balance,Description));
}
}
```

Here is the sub class

```
public class Transactions extends Account {
private java.util.Date DateTransaction;
private char TransactionType;
private double amount; 

private String description;

public Transactions(){}

/*public Transactions(int ID, double balance, String NAME){
    super(ID,balance,NAME);
} */

public String Transactions1(char TYPE, double AMOUNT,double balance, String DESCRIPTION){
    this.TransactionType = TYPE; 
    this.amount = AMOUNT;
    this.description = DESCRIPTION;
    java.util.Date DateTransactedUpon = getDateTransaction();
    return "Transaction:" + this.TransactionType + "\nAmount: " + this.amount
    +"\n"+this.description +"\nThis Date:"+ DateTransactedUpon;     
}

public char getTransactionType() {
    return TransactionType;
}

public void setTransactionType(char transactionType) {
    TransactionType = transactionType;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public java.util.Date getDateTransaction() {
    return DateTransaction;
}



}
```

When doing a simple testing with this code.

```
public class TestAccount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Account A = new Account(1122,1000.0,"George");

        A.deposit(30);
        A.deposit(40);
        A.deposit(50);
        A.withdraw(5);
        A.withdraw(4);
        A.withdraw(2);  
    }
}
```

Comment: That's all the stacktrace or is it way longer? An StackOverflowError suggest too many method calls, which in turn suggest infinite recursions (a method calling itself, either directly or through calling other methods than then call the original method). But an stacktrace that short does not support that possibility, and I cannot locate recursive calls in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, the recursion:

```
public class Account {
  protected int id; 
  private String name;

  protected double balance;     
  private double annualInterestRate;
  private java.util.Date dateCreated;
  ArrayList<Object> transaction =  new ArrayList<Object>();

  Transactions tr = new Transactions(); <---
```

Each `Transaction` is an `Account` (because of the `extends Account`; each time you create a `Transaction` the initialization code of the `Account` part is also called.

And, what happens when you initialize the `Account` part of the instance? Bingo! A new `Transactions` object is created as an attribute of the class.

A few points:

- It makes no sense for `Transaction` to extend `Account`, since a `transaction` is not an account. A subclass relationship is called an "is-an" relationship, any instance of the subclass is also an instance of the superclass.
- It also makes no sense to create an empty transaction when creating an account...

Answer (score 0):

Transactions extends Account, but Account has an instance of Transactions. So Transactions has an instance of Transactions, which has an instance of Transactions, which has an instance of Transactions, etc.

Transactions probably should not extend Account since there is not an "IS A" relationship between them.